# Are there any words describing normal breathing?

Tags: vocabulary, sounds, onomatopoeia

I am not sure but I can't find any words that describe normal calm breathing. Something that describes the exhale of a breath or blowing air out from your mouth. Not frantic or puffed breathing just relaxed sounds like a sigh. But a sigh describes what the person is doing... not really the actual sound... Are there any English words for this?

Comment: **Sigh** is also a sound. ("to make a sound suggesting a sigh" OR "the act or sound of sighing.")  Source: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sighed

Comment: Not sure if there's a one word term for this. I think most would just say *regular breathing* or a regular rhythm of breathing

Comment: Just *breathing* itself. (Or *breathe* or *breath*, depending on how it's used.) Any other word would be used for something *unusual*. But if you have to draw a contrast with an adverb, then *regular* or *normal* as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The most common word for breathing is "**respiration**" which is often broken down by definition into two actions - to ***inhale and exhale***. There is also the technical term for normal breathing which is "**eupnoea**". However, the word "**breathing**" itself would seem to be descriptive enough for most usages.

If you are searching for an *onomatopoeic* word for the *(sound of) regular breathing*, I did find "**susurration**". It is a noun mostly used for a low, indistinct whispering sound. I found this online descriptive usage - *susurration
[a soft, whispering or rustling sound] of the breeze
in the wayside grasses*. However, it could be used as descriptive of breathing sounds as well - e.g. normal/calm/slow/indistinct breaths could be replaced with "**susurrations**" (the inhalations/exhalations of normal breathing in context). It can also be used in the adjective form "**susurrous**" - e.g. *susurrous respiration/breaths/sounds*.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/respiration

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/inhale

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/exhale

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/eupnoea

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/susurration

Comment: Yeah but i'm trying to find a word that describes the sound that breathing makes not a word for the actual thing itself. Thanks tho!!

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you that, from the standpoint of someone administering first aid, the way to express what you're trying to express (the sound of normal breathing) is **"calm breathing"**. This, however, would be clarified with a respiratory rate in terms of breaths per minute, because "calm" would depend on multiple factors: age, elevation, weight, and they would all correlate to a respiratory rate. Knowing the respiratory rate would be the best measure of normal breathing.

Now, it also sounds like you are trying to capture a sound to calm breathing, and this is merely a matter of perception. A medic would likely comment on the sound of breathing by noting audible elements: a rasp, a wheeze, a hiccup,  which *might* indicate an abnormality. Or, they would note nothing abnormal at all, which is to say, stable breathing with no signs of a disturbance. And this would be noted as "calm breathing". That is to say, there is no single sound associated with calm breathing. We all breathe differently if you get down to the *sounds* we make.